# Viewing every single TFS changeset?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, changeset, source-control-explorer

I am trying to view every single changeset in my project's history... at least the last 1000, say.  So I ran the command:

```
tf history $/MyProject /recursive /format:brief
```

... at the VS command line.  This popped up a history window with most of the changesets in the MyProject project, but even here there si the odd changeset missing.  For example, the list of changeset IDs goes:
3956
3955
3954
3953
3952
3949
3948
3947
[...]

Changesets 3950-3951 are not shown; why?  And how can I force them to be shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change set numbers are [shared on the server level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/04/19/team-foundation-server-2010-key-concepts.aspx). Maybe those change sets are part of another project?

EDIT:
shared on the collection level since TFS 2010

Comment: Doh!  I'm dumb... this was exactly the problem.  I checked the history of the server, and those missing changes were there and had been done in another project.  Thanks!